# Pull to Refresh on Cordova Hybrid React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, touch, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to find a Pull to Refresh implementation for React that will work on mobile. My app is built in React (not React Native), with a Redux store. We are then using Cordova to get some of the native capabilities on the mobile devices.

I have tried the following things:

- [React Pull to Refresh NPM package](https://github.com/bryaneaton13/react-pull-to-refresh): 
  This worked beautifully on the web, but it breaks the scroll
  functionality on both iOS and Android.. There's an open issue that
  hasn't been addressed about in a year.
- [React Touch NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-touch): The closest I could come to getting pull-to-refresh using this package was to wrap the `<div>` in both `<Holdable>` and`<Swipable>`. The scroll works, the pull to refresh LOOKS like it works, but my handleRefresh() function is never called. See code below.

NOTE: I know that the handleRefresh() function itself works, because it was called and functioned properly in the *browser* with the React Pull to Refresh package.

```js
    class Home extends React.Component {
        componentWillMount() {
            if (this.props.homeTiles.isLoaded === false) {
                this.props.loadHomeTiles();
            }
            if(!this.props.loginLocale.isLoaded) {
                this.props.loadLoginLocale();
            }

            // load the messages
            this.props.loadLocalesFromLocalStorage(this.props.loginLocale.language);
        }
        handleRefresh() {
            this.props.refreshAllData();
            this.props.loadHomeTiles();
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <Holdable>
                    <Swipeable onSwipeDown={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}>
                        <div>
                            <TileContainer tiles={this.props.homeTiles.tiles} messageFor={this.props.messageFor} source={"home"} />
                        </div>
                    </Swipeable>
                </Holdable>
            );
        }
    }
```

Questions:

1. Can you spot any errors in my code that would prevent the handleRefresh() function from firing?
2. Is this the correct way to implement Pull to Refresh with the React Touch package?
3. Can anyone suggest another way to implement Pull to Refresh, which would work on a Hybrid Cordova React app?